# Increase element's order through a SASS variable

Tags: css, sass

I'm looking for the best method in SASS to iterate a class's `order` to go up `1` every 4 item.  I came up with the following that gets the result I wanted, but comes with a lot of *perhaps* unnecessary markup.

```css
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    order: 3;  
    background: green;
  }
}  
@for $i from 4 through 6 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    order: 1;
    background: blue;
  }
}  
@for $i from 7 through 9 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    order: 2;  
    background: red;
  }
}
```

[Full Example of Code Working on Codepen](http://codepen.io/ekfuhrmann/pen/XjpEOV)

Is there a better way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you're asking with a single loop and some math.  There's probably an even more efficient way, but this is what I could come up with:

```
.box {
  @for $i from 0 through 9 {
    $c : $i + 1;
    &:nth-child(#{$c}) {
      order: (($i - $i % 3) / 3) + 1;  
    }
  }  
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
.box:nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
.box:nth-child(2) { order: 1; }
.box:nth-child(3) { order: 1; }
.box:nth-child(4) { order: 2; }
.box:nth-child(5) { order: 2; }
.box:nth-child(6) { order: 2; }
.box:nth-child(7) { order: 3; }
.box:nth-child(8) { order: 3; }
.box:nth-child(9) { order: 3; }
.box:nth-child(10) { order: 4; }
```

Note that counter starts with zero, which is why I needed to use the $c variable.  There might be a way around that but it was killing the groups of threes when I tried to get around it. You can change the ending variable in the loop (from 9) to whatever number you want and it will continue incrementing groups of 3.

**In Action:**

http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/6506fa7b74b2341539b1373d943cb9cc

Comment: This works great and is far improved from what I had (especially since I was having to repeat my own `for` loops numerous times for different elements/media queries (in my project) so this is a massive improvement over that.  Thanks!